# Mounted Docker Volumes Are Empty

Tags: docker, macos, mount, docker-volume

**Problem**

The `$(pwd)/app` directory locally contains many subdirectories and files. So does the directory in my Docker image `/usr/local/app`. When I run the following

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/app:/usr/local/app my_image bash
```

the command is successful, but the `/usr/local/app` directory is now empty. It seems that I've mounted *something* to this location, but it's empty.

Is there something that I'm missing here that I should be aware of?

**Context**

This exact command used to succeed. The only recent change is that I uninstalled Docker Desktop in favor of just using the Docker Engine running on a local minikube instance. I'm using `Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b63a` on MacOS Ventura.

Comment: Where actually is the current directory?  Have you done any of the setup to [mount the host directory into the minikube VM](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/)?  Should this content be built into an image and `COPY`ed in a Dockerfile, rather than injected via a bind mount?

Comment: I think that the minikube mounting is exactly what I'm looking for! I'm going to check right now. I'm only running the container for local testing, and I want to make edits without rebuilding, but great question. Yes, I want it copied for all my deployments.

Comment: Yep, confirmed, this was the solution. Want to write an answer so I can mark it? If not, I'll write one tomorrow.